# OutOfMemoryError (unable to create new native thread) in a Web Service

Tags: java, centos, out-of-memory, tomcat8

In our company, we've got an EC2 instance from Amazon Web Services, m1.medium size and running CentOS.

We've got a Tomcat 8 (tomcat installed from os repository), running a single web service.

Tomcat and the web service seem to run right, but it comes a momment when a OutOfMemoryError is thrown and WS' methods can't be executed. The only thing that can be done is to restart Tomcat. This is a stack trace sample:

org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
Root cause

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
>       java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
>       java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:714)
>       com.amazonaws.http.IdleConnectionReaper.registerConnectionManager(IdleConnectionReaper.java:80)
>       com.amazonaws.http.ConnectionManagerFactory.createPoolingClientConnManager(ConnectionManagerFactory.java:49)
>       com.amazonaws.http.HttpClientFactory.createHttpClient(HttpClientFactory.java:113)
>       com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.(AmazonHttpClient.java:213)
>       com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:136)
>       com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.(AmazonS3Client.java:481)
>       com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.(AmazonS3Client.java:460)
>       com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.(AmazonS3Client.java:442)
>       com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.(AmazonS3Client.java:413)
>       com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.(AmazonS3Client.java:395)
>       com.ingartek.ws.zendesk_bizkaibus.service.AWSGateway.(AWSGateway.java:56)
>       com.ingartek.ws.zendesk_bizkaibus.service.PlantillasService.(PlantillasService.java:39)
>       com.ingartek.ws.zendesk_bizkaibus.service.GeneralService.getDocumentoRespuestaQueja(GeneralService.java:894)
>       com.ingartek.ws.zendesk_bizkaibus.rest.DocumentosResource.generarDocumentoRespuestaQueja(DocumentosResource.java:113)
>       sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
>       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleSimpleCORS(CorsFilter.java:301)
>       org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:169)

I've been looking for a solution to this problem, finding several interesting pages like [this](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-monitoring/how-to-solve-javalangoutofmemoryerror-unable-to-create-new-native-thread). It seems to me that the problem is not webservice-related nor tomcat-related, but os-related. Why? When the exception is thrown, I access to my Tomcat server status page and I don't see that the jvm memory is exhausted. Now, for instance, it looks like this:

> Free memory: 563.22 MB Total memory: 989.93 MB Max memory: 3959.50 MB

So, what can I do? Thanks for your suggestion.

Note: I'm running VisualVM to monitor the JVM and look for memory, cpu and threads.

EDIT

I've found the following in my logs:

```
23-Jan-2017 09:50:49.450 ADVERTENCIA [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ws_zendesk_bizkaibus] appears to have started a thread named [New I/O boss #3] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil.select(SelectorUtil.java:68)
org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.select(AbstractNioSelector.java:434)
org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:212)
org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.run(NioClientBoss.java:42)
org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Are you leaking threads? You'll run out of them faster than you'll run out of memory.

Comment: If usinng any InputStream, please don't forgot to close it after it is used.(inputStream.close).

Comment: @Kayaman I'm updating my question.

Comment: @HAXM I usually close streams and every stuff which need so.

Comment: Well, like I said, observe if you're leaking threads. You should notice pretty easily if the amount of threads keeps growing constantly. Then see which threads are not getting freed and find the bug and fix it.

Comment: I'll revise my code now. Thanks @Kayaman

Comment: I said to observe which threads are leaking (if you have a thread leak). I didn't tell you to revise your code.

Comment: In the profiler I can see lots of "New I/O boss" and "New I/O worker" running since I restarted tomcat.

Comment: You should see Runtime_Thread_Count of your process and Allowed_Thread_count of your process and If your runtime thread count will  try to get new thread over the allowed count,You are most likely to hit the above error. You can try the command below :

Comment: echo -n max Threads:;echo  $(cat /proc/$(echo $(ps -p $(ps -ef | grep PROCESS_NAME | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}') -o pid= ))/limits | grep "Max processes" | sed 's/  */ /g' | cut -d\  -f3);echo  $(cat /proc/$(echo $(ps -p $(ps -ef | grep PROCESS_NAME | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}') -o pid= ))/status | grep Threads);

Comment: @DilipSinghKasana "cut: the delimiter must be a single character"

Comment: I've been able to mitigate OutOfMemory error for the time being. I had some stream unclosed, plus some other resources which required to be closed. I'll inform with news.